# TcpClient (C#) native equivalent in Java

Tags: java, c#, sockets, network-programming

I know that this question regards on a little bit of opinion, but I'm not a Java full-time developer (I develop mainly on C# and other MS technologies).

In C# world, we have TcpClient (a simple to use socket type that fulfill my needs). Does Java have this kind of socket?

I just want to know: is there a native equivalent for TcpClient (C#) in Java? Should I implement my own TcpClient with sockets or go with Apache MINA/Netty?

I just want to do basic TCP communication (open connection, send, receive, close connection) with an embedded device using Java.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Yes, there is equivalent.

Comment: If I knew anything about C#, I could tell you.  What you are describing sounds like a regular Socket.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes in java you can get socket class in java.net.Socket.[Link Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)

You can get a sample code using socket [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)